# How to compile boost with -g debug flag?

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, jam

I want to recompile our boost library, but with the -g, debugging flag enabled. I've been reading and see that we build boost with `jam`. While I know `make` very well, `jam` has always eluded me and my frustration is mounting.

Comment: I fond the properties `cxxflags` and `cflags`, that looks like what i want to do... trying that now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry. I know answering your own question is distasteful, but I was able to figure this out shortly after posting. the `cxxflags` and `cflags` properties are what I need to use, as outlined at: http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html under the PROPERTIES sectin.

Comment: On the contrary, answering your own questions is just fine.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: @PlasmaHH Reading the extended fine manual. The normal build instructions didn't have it.. but then again, it *IS* labeled quick start.